# How do you debug ASP.NET applications under IIS7 on Vista?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, iis-7, cassini

There is a post on IIS.net titled "[Using Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/)", but I don't quite believe that's what people do. (Among other gems, it suggests publishing your web app after every change.)

If you debug your ASP.NET applications in IIS7 instead of Cassini, I would love to hear your methods, tips, and tricks.

**Edit**: I'm referring specifically to local debugging.

Comment: Are you referring to local or remote debugging?

Comment: I got so sick of Cassini bugs I create the site in IIS then open through visual studio and debug with F5, since then I have been a happier person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply attach Visual Studio to the IIS worker process, if you have multiple app pools then you can run "issapp" to get the appropriate PID.

I never debug by clicking "Start Debugging".

This has a nice advantage of working on remote servers as well, if you have installed msvcmon.

Comment: I've been doing this for the last 2 months, and it's definitely a huge improvement over F5.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I pointed you toward that guide, but as I look closer at it I think that's a little more elaborate than what I do. I have done the following:

1. Create a web site in IIS for your project.
2. Add a custom host header to that site, for example `http://mysite:*/ or http://mysite:80/`
3. Open the `hosts` file located at `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc` in notepad (Run As Admin if you're on Vista) and add the following line:

   ```
   mysite        127.0.0.1
   ```

   If you have more than one host header on your website in IIS, you need to have each one represented in the `hosts` file.

Now, when you press `F5` in Visual Studio, the site will open with the url `http://mysite` and you'll be able to debug, set breakpoints etc as usual, except with no Cassini related problems... ;)

**Edit:** For clarification, I just want to point out that I have never had to attach any process to VS, as far as I know. At the very least I do not have to do it every time.

Comment: So if your code is in some folder like c:\code\trunk\mywebsite, you set that path to be the root directory for the web site?

Comment: Yes. In IIS, you can choose the root path for your site as you wish, so you set the path to wherever you store your ASP.Net Web Project files.

Answer (score 1):

Well, setting up IIS 7 for debugging isn't terribly tricky, but what I prefer to do to save time (and if I'm uninterested in debugging from a cold start) is to launch the Web Application/Web Site in a web browser first - let ASP.net precompile etc.

Then I'll attach to the IIS process using Visual Studio.  Once attached I can go about setting breakpoints and debugging, I find this is a faster way to get going.

Answer (score 1):

I launch Visual Studio as an Administrator, then Debug > Attach to Process > w3wp.exe.

Comment: Thanks, this is good for when you don't have the entire website open in VS